# What is (if any) the standard approach for designing out of core/ external memory algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, cuda, gpgpu, scientific-computing, hpc

I am looking for rules of thumb for designing algorithms where the data is accessed slowly due to limitations of disk speed, pci speed(gpgpu) or other bottleneck.

Also, how does one manage gpgpu programs where the memory of the application exceeds gpgpu memory?

Comment: This is a really broad question, so much so that I doubt it is sensibly answerable as written. Do you have something specific in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the GPU memory should not be an arbitrary limitation on the size of data for algorithms.  The GPU memory could be considered to be a "cache" of data that the GPU is currently operating on, but many GPU algorithms are designed to operate on more data than can fit in the "cache".   This is accomplished by moving data to and from the GPU while computation is going on, and the GPU has specific [concurrent execution and copy/compute overlap mechanisms](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution)  to enable this.

This usually implies that independent work can be completed on sections of the data, which is typically a good indicator for acceleration in a parallelizable application.  Conceptually, this is similar to large scale MPI applications (such as high performance linpack) which break the work into pieces and then send the pieces to various machines (MPI ranks) for computation.

If the amount of work to be done on the data is small compared to the cost to transfer the data, then the data transfer speed will still become the bottleneck, unless it is addressed directly via changes to the storage system.

The basic approach to handling out-of-core or algorithms where the data set is too large to fit in GPU memory  all at once is to determine a version of the algorithm which can work on separable data, and then craft a "pipelined" algorithm to work on the data in chunks.  An example tutorial which covers such a programming technique is [here](https://vimeo.com/442361242) (focus starts around 40 minute mark, but the whole video is relevant).

Comment: That video is unavailable, can you update it?

Comment: I was unable to locate the video also, so I have updated the link to reflect a different resource.